# Authentication signalr communication between ASP.NET Core application and a React SPA application failing (Microsoft Identity Platform)

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core, signalr, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a React application which is connected with an ASP.NET Core application via SignalR.
I'm trying to authenticate this application by using Microsoft Identity Platform.
I tried to do this by using this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react) for the react app and
I used "Adding authentication to our SignalR web App" from this [blog](https://dev.to/425show/secure-net-5-signalr-solutions-with-azure-ad-36ec) to setup the ASP.NET Core application. As a result of this, I'm able to sign in to the Microsoft Identity Platform and to request an access token.
I use this token to setup the SignalR connection like this:

```
      useEffect(() => {
if (accessToken) {
  const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hub", { accessTokenFactory: () => accessToken,
      logger: LogLevel.Trace
     })
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();

  connection
    .start()
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      setConnectedState(false);
    })
    .then(() => {
      //Some code
    });
  setHubConnection(connection);
}}, [accessToken]);
```

However the negotiation to upgrade to a websocket fails with the follow log message:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
> DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.

The strange thing however is that the signarlR connection successfully falls back to "LongPolling". "LongPolling" doesn't work with a different configuration, so my msal configuration seems okay. I checked all my config files, but I can't find a mistake in the configuration. I would like to know where to search for my mistake.

Comment: Does you server support websocket?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng the same problem occurs when I'm using Azure App services with websockets turned on and locally when debugging with Visual Studio and IIS Express. I added the URI of the App service and localhost to my client App Registration.